# Error String types not allowed (at 'src' with value 'drawable/ic_dialog_email')

Tags: android

i am new to this and this is the first project i have started and at very first time i am getting this error.
i havnt had any image added to it.its just first "hello world" one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.nehal.testandroid1.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: put @ before `drawable/ic_dialog_email`.

Comment: `android:src="@drawable/ic_dialog_email"`

Answer (score 1):

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

In the above FAB Button,

Replace: `android:src="drawable/ic_dialog_email"`

With: `android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"`

It will work.

Answer (score 1):

Put `@` before `drawable/ic_dialog_email` like this

```
android:src="@drawable/ic_dialog_email"
```